# lineno workaround reset impossible using pagewise/switch etc

Tags: double-sided, line-numbering, lineno

I'm having a difficulty/impossibility with the lineno package.
What I want to write is a book, so double-sided, with different sections each anew beginning at 1.

So the setup is quite simple and working well except for the reset to number 1.

```
\usepackage[switch*]{lineno}
```

and then, in the document:

```
\begin{linenumbers}
\modulolinenumbers
%...text...
\end{linenumbers}
```

So far so good.

In the user manual is a warning that it is impossible to reset the counter in any 'pagewise' mode. 
Well, that is exactly what I want to do. Every new chapter has to start with number 1. My question: is there any workaround?
My document setup is a mainfile and subfiles, quite simple:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{preambule}
\begin{document}
\subfile{10corvus_et_vulpes}
\newpage
\subfile{20commentarii}
\end{document}
```

Now my own idea is that it will perhaps help when there is a quite hard break, a new start between the two imported files. However, I do not know how to fix this. And I do not want to start the pagenumbering again.
Here I add a MnonWE, using the standard formatting and using \resetlinenumber, obviously without succes:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[switch*]{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{title1}
\begin{linenumbers}
\modulolinenumbers
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{linenumbers}
\newpage
\section{title2}
\begin{linenumbers}
\modulolinenumbers
\resetlinenumber
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your response in advance.

Jan

Comment: Do you want to restart the numbering at the beginning of each page or at the beginning of each chapter?

Comment: Hi DG, at each chapter/section. So, taken my MnWE: I want to start with 1 at the beginning of the second section. For clarity I just added a \newpage-command between the sections.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [lineno-manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lineno/lineno.pdf) there are two modes:

1. *running*, which allows resets, but no margin switching
2. *pagewise*, which allows margin switching, but no resets

And then you can simulate running numbers in *pagewise* mode, which still doesn't allow margin switching. In other words: This won't work.

---

You still could try `reledmac` which is probably overkill (and rather complicated), but it let's you switch margins and reset the numbering:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\linenummargin{outer}

\chapter{Something}
\section{This}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
  \lipsum[1-2]
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{That}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
  \lipsum[3-4]
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{No end in sight}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
  \lipsum[5-6]
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you really need to switch and reset the line numbers, and switching to ConTeXt is an option, you could start from here:

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
\setuplinenumbering[step=5,
                    style=\tt\tfxx,
                    align=outer,
                    location=inner]

\starttext

\startsection[title={Knuth}]
\startlinenumbering
  \input knuth
\stoplinenumbering
\stopsection

\startsection[title={Tufte}]
\startlinenumbering
  \dorecurse{2}{\input tufte\par}
\stoplinenumbering

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can! Like the author himself declares, to use lineo.sty in a two-sides environment, you have to 'abuse' the pagewise-option. Switch is a pagewise-variant.

Comment: Dear DG, thank you for taking time to interpret me... When you compile your own MWE, Latex is indeed succesful to reset the counter at a new section, but the switch doesn't work anymore. So all linenumbers are either in the left or right margin. I want the combination. This seems to be impossible from the lineno-package, and that's the reason I seek for a workaround.

Comment: @J.Bart `reledmac` appears to be able to do, what you want

Comment: Thank you, this works indeed. However, loads of new problems occur: non floating marginnotes/sidenotes, wrapfig disfunctioning/needs reformulation... So, hmm...

Comment: @J.Bart How badly do you need switching line numbers? Are they a hard requirement? Many classical editions have the line numbering running on one side despite being set double sided (e.g. Diels/Kranz), so maybe you are willing to reconsider your aesthetical preferences...

Comment: well, I use them in combination with quite extensive use of marginpar/sidenotes/marginnote; these notes really have to be in the outer margin, leaving no option for the numbers than to be in the inner margin. What I want to make is something resembling the page-setup of the Latin method of Orberg (easily to find an example on the internet). I am now inspecting the memoir-class...

Comment: Well, in this case I would recommend switching to ConTeXt.